# String PHP Spell Wrongly

Tags: php

PHP spelling frustrated me. I keep trying to add `". ABC ."` and `'. ABC .'`. But it still doesnt work. Like my code below:

```
echo '
    <div class="box">
       <p> '.$obj->name.': "'.$obj->message.'" </p>
       <p class="right"> '.date_format('.$obj->message_date.', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');.' </p> 
    </div>
';
```

The problem is **DATE FORMAT** doesn't want to show on a webpage. Any idea?

Comment: You should turn on error reporting if you haven't already. Then you would already have an idea of the issue.

Comment: ^ http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ^

Comment: I have turned on the error and it doesn't work.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* - That doesn't tell us much. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php

Comment: When I put `'.$obj->message_date.'`, it showed up on the webpage. And I wanted to put date_format only. The errors didn't show anything even though I have put this error `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` on the top of the page.

Comment: You need to "display" the error `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` add that under `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

Comment: Uhm, it showed this "Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime"

Comment: Well there you go ;-) read the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
'.date_format('.$obj->message_date.', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');.'
```

to

```
'.date_format($obj->message_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s').'
```

If `$obj->message_date` is a string, you need to convert it to a date object first:

```
'.date_format(date_create($obj->message_date), 'Y-m-d H:i:s').'
```

Comment: No, this one also not showing on the webpage

Comment: Then find out what the error is. Enable error reporting and it will show an error.

Comment: Updated my answer with an other idea.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is you are not concatenating your PHP into your string correctly.

```
       echo '
        <div class="box">
           <p> '.$obj->name.': "'.$obj->message.'" </p>
           <p class="right"> '.date_format($obj->message_date, "Y-m-d H:i:s").' </p> 
        </div> ';
```

I think this should not provide errors on that front. If the page still doesn't load you will need to look at the $obj to see if there is actually a message_date property and that is a date.

For more information see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php